# Laravel 8 Upload image not succesful (always redirect back)

Tags: php, laravel, image, controller

i'm using laravel 8 to make a CMS for a website, and i encounter this error after i need to upload an image.

this is my web.php for the route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'webcontrol',  'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
    Route::resource('/banners', App\Http\Controllers\Webcontrol\BannerController::class);
    Route::resource('/publications', App\Http\Controllers\Webcontrol\PublicationController::class);
});
```

and this is my form:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
    <label for="" class="d-block">Image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" required name="image_desktop" value="{{ $model->image_desktop }}">
    @error('image_desktop')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
    @enderror
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
    <label for="" class="d-block">Mobile Image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" required name="image_mobile" value="{{ $model->image_mobile }}">
    @error('image_mobile')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
    @enderror
</div>
```

and this is my controller:

```
public function store(PublicationRequest $request)
    {
        $publication = new Publication;

        if ($request->hasFile('image_desktop'))
        {
            request()->validate(['image_desktop' => 'file|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,pdf|max:2048']);
            $uploadedObject = $request->file('image_desktop');
            $imageDesktop = md5(time()).'.' .$uploadedObject->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $uploadedObject->move(public_path('img/uploads'), $imageDesktop);
        }
        if ($request->hasFile('image_mobile'))
        {
            request()->validate(['image_mobile' => 'file|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,pdf|max:2048']);
            $uploadedObject = $request->file('image_mobile');
            $imageMobile = md5(time()).'.' .$uploadedObject->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $uploadedObject->move(public_path('img/uploads'), $imageMobile);
        }
        $publication->image_desktop = $imageDesktop ?? '';
        $publication->image_mobile = $imageMobile ?? '';

        $publication->save();

        // return $publication;
        return redirect()->route('publications.index')->with('success', 'Your form has been submitted.');
    }
```

and i have a Request for my store function in Controller:
[image: Request for Store]

what i have done is, it was successful before i use the if function for uploaded image to go to public folder.

i have already chmod 777 for public (localhost, so don't worry about the permission)

Comment: Do you have error message?

Comment: please do not put up images of code, code is text and belongs in a code block in your question, thanks ... also you have 2 different sets of validation happening on the same fields

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm afraid of too many codes in question so it can't be posted @lagbox

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth i dont have any error message, it's just redirecting back to the form

Comment: of course your can post the code, you put up an image instead of just copy and pasting the code like you did for the other files you had, that image has less lines of code then your other code blocks that are 'text' not images

Comment: Can you clarify Upload Image not successful? Do you mean the file is not saved in the server? URL path where the file is not saved?

Comment: does $imageDesktop have value? $imageMobile?

Comment: I think $imageDesktop's value is md5(time)+ extension. Not the image path itself.

Comment: i will try to change imageDesktop's value to your recommendation, please wait @Mr.Kenneth

Answer (score 0):

Try returning false for function authorize

Comment: 403 | THIS ACTION IS UNAUTHORIZED. it return this after i click submit